# Android activity closes two times

Tags: android

i have an android app and it works pretty well but just recently it started to show a problem.
The problem is that it starts normally but when i click back it creates a new main activity and when i click back another time the application closes correctly .
Here there's a video of that:  https://streamable.com/s/s7m8c/snygay?muted=1
I can't get ahead of this problem by myself so does anyone knows why it happens?

Edit:
The activity is launched with this code.

```
mHandler = new Handler();
    mActivityLaunchRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mActivityLaunchRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And the onBackPressed is not overridden

Comment: please add some code

Comment: how are you starting activity and have overriden onBackPress method?

Comment: remove finish()

Comment: Why are you using a `Runnable()` to call `startActivity()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop adding the splash screen activity to the stack.You can do this this like below in your `manifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreen"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

Then you can remove `finish()` in your code snippet.

Note: Another way to do this is to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the correct way of creating a splash screen!

This is how I usually implement it -

```
ImageView splashImg = (ImageView)(findViewById(R.id.splash_img));
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splashImg,"alpha",0,1);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(3f));
        objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                Log.i(TAG,"on animation start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                Log.i(TAG,"on animation end");
                startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
                Log.i(TAG,"on animation cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
                Log.i(TAG,"on animation repeat");
            }
        });
        objectAnimator.start();
```

In your MainActivity, override onBackPressed() as -

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finishAffinity();
    }
```

[Here's a short tutorial on ObjectAnimator](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128105/introduction-android-animations)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying! I resolved using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY but this is a very good way for doing a splash screen. I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

### Add Clear Top before startActivity intent to MainActivity Class

```
mHandler = new Handler();
mActivityLaunchRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This method will be executed once the timer is over
        // Start app main activity
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(i);
        // close this activity
        finish();
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(mActivityLaunchRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```